# How to use the view_mode in hook_preprocess_flag?

Tags: 7, theming, flags

I'm using Drupal 7 and [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag).

I try to modify the output of my flags according to the view mode with preprocess_flag :

```
function mytheme_preprocess_flag(&$variables) {
  $variables['full'] = $variables['view_mode'] == 'full';
  if ($variables['full']) {
...
  }
}
```

But i have an error : `Notice : Undefined index: view_mode dans publiu_preprocess_flag()`.

Do you know how to use the view_mode in hook_preprocess_flag ?

Answer (score 2):

view_mode key is not in variables object, which you get as argument. You can check for the same, by printing variables object.

```
print '<pre>';
print_r($variables);
print '</pre>';
```

However if u still want to get view mode, you can use somewhat like below.

```
function bartik_preprocess_flag(&$variables) {
  $arg_1 = arg(1);
  if( isset($arg_1) && !empty($arg_1) ) {
    $menu_obj = menu_get_object();
    $menu_obj_content = $menu_obj['content'];
    foreach($menu_obj_content as $menu_key=>$menu_val) {
      $node_view_mode = $menu_val['#view_mode'];
      break;
    }
    print $node_view_mode;
  }
}
```

Here node_view_mode will return "View Mode" of current node.